# JSON feed from MySQL works, but not with more than x records

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get FullCalendar to work with my MySQL db. This works when I limit my query to 25 records. When I change my sql query to limit to, lets say 35 records, Fullcalendar will not add any event and basically keeps loading.

I checked with firebug what the JSON response was and in both times it's complete.

At first I thought the problem was the SQL query. The DB is 5000+ records long but the JSON response is loading in less then 200ms.

I'm using the demo json.html file for testing. will post the function here:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "json-events.php",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my json-events.php

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL server.");

    $Exec = mysql_query("select Brand, date_in from planning ORDER BY date_in Desc Limit 35",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close();

    $events = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Exec)) {
        $eventArray['title'] = $row['Brand'];
        $eventArray['start'] = $row['date_in'];
        $eventsArray['allDay'] = "";
        $events[] = $eventArray;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

This is the JSON response:

> [{"title":"Volkswagen Passat","start":"2011-04-28"},{"title":"Seat Alhambra","start":"2011-04-28"},{"title":"Ford  Focus","start":"2011-04-20"},{"title":"BMW  5-Serie","start":"2011-04-20"},{"title":"Ford  Mondeo","start":"2011-04-20"},{"title":"Volkswagen Caddy","start":"2011-04-20"},{"title":"Opel  Zafira","start":"2011-04-18"},{"title":"Mazda  3","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Opel  Vectra","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Peugeot  207","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Volkswagen  Golf","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Volvo  V90","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Volvo V50","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Volkswagen  Polo","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Volkswagen Golf","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Ford Mondeo","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Audi ","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"BMW 525i","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Renault Laguna","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Opel Astra","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Seat Alambhra","start":"2011-04-14"},{"title":"Peugeot 307","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Hyundai  Atos","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Citroen  Xsara Picasso","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Opel Astra","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Volkswagen  Golf","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Peugeot  307","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Volkswagen  Passat","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":null,"start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Citroen C1","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Toyota  Camry","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Toyota  Aygo","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"Nissan  Qashqai","start":"2011-04-13"},{"title":"BMW 3 touring","start":"2011-04-12"},{"title":"Toyota  Prius","start":"2011-04-12"}]

I tried everything I could come up with, I've spend 5 hours trying to make this work.

Is there anyone who has any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the error is in your database.

In your JSON feed you have an entry that is

```
{"title":null,"start":"2011-04-13"}
```

That null is probably what is holding you up.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer i will investigate further, The database will have blank spaces and/or NULLS sometimes but i can filter them out with SQL. I did notice when there was no title the calendar would just show whitespace as title.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found part of the problem, special characters in the name turn up as NULLS in the JSON output, names like Renault Mégane. so i changed the charset to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="Latin-1"></meta>
```

I also changed the JSON and added:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

The're still some minor issues, but it works! thanks for your help!